# Convert NoSQL like syntax to MySQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is mysql table structure

| item_id | StockNo | SizeCd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12003 | UNIT |
| 2 | 12007 | JOGO |
| 3 | 12008 | PACOTE |
| 4 | 12033 | JOGO |
| 5 | 12034 | JOGO |
| 6 | 12038 | UNIT |

I'm using plugin called `DevExtreme` for remote data grid. It's API request looks like below.

```
{
  from: get_data
  skip: 0
  take: 50
  requireTotalCount: true
  filter: [["SizeCd","=","UNIT"],"or",["SizeCd","=","JOGO"]]
}
```

Where filter is what I need help with. What I want is I want to convert this string into MySQL where condition syntax.

I tried using php functions like `array_merge` `join` but couldn't get it to work. Sometimes it place quotes to both sides or sometimes quotes were missing. It should be like field name without quotes and value with quotes. Like in mysql where syntax.

Sorry for bad formatting and grammar mistakes.

Comment: Can you show actual code and structures?

Comment: What happens if there is a quote character inside the strings e.g. `["SizeCd","=","JO'GO"]`?

Comment: @SalmanA Maybe I will escape it using addslashes or consider there won't be this type of case.

Comment: @Justinas I have edited my question. Hope you could understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this array:

```php
$array = [["SizeCd","=","UNIT"],"or",["SizeCd","=","JOGO"],"or",["SizeCd","=","PACOTE"]];
```

#### For PDO

You can use the following functions:

```php
function arrayToQuery(string $tableName, array $array) : string 
{
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `{$tableName}` WHERE ";

    foreach($array as $item) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            $select .= "`{$item[0]}` {$item[1]} ?";
        } else {
            $select .= " {$item} ";
        }
    }

    return $select;
}

function arrayToParams(array $array) : array  
{
    $return = [];
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            $return[] = $item[2];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

var_dump(
    arrayToQuery("x", $array),
    arrayToParams($array)
);
```

Output:

```
string(66) "SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE `SizeCd` = ? or `SizeCd` = ? or `SizeCd` = ?"
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "UNIT"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "JOGO"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "PACOTE"
}
```

##### Example using PDO

```php
$conn = /* your conn object */;
$sql = arrayToQuery("your_table_name", $array);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(arrayToParams($array));
```

#### Update: For Mysqli

For mysqli you can use the following function:

```php
function arrayToQueryMysqli($mysqli, string $table, array $array) : string 
{
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `{$table}` WHERE ";
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            $select .= "`{$item[0]}` {$item[1]} '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($item[2]) . "'";
        } else {
            $select .= " {$item} ";
        }
    }
    return $select;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(/* Your settings */);
$query = arrayToQueryMysqli($mysqli, "tablename", $array);
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks man worked very good. I had to make minor changes but looks like it's working. One request though, can you upvote question if you think it's valid?